# How to assign ConnectionId signalR value to different pages

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr

**I am working with signalR in Asp.net and Send message to specific user. I have 2 pages to process as follows:**

**Page1.aspx**

```
<div class="">
    <button id="_chat" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="..............">
        <i class="fas fa-comments"></i> Chat
    </button>
</div>
<input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />

<script>
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
        registerClientMethods(chatHub);
    });
    function registerClientMethods(chatHub) {
        // Calls when user successfully logged in
        chatHub.client.onConnected = function (id, userName) {

            $('#hdId').val(id);
            $('#hdUserName').val(userName);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Page2.aspx**

```
<div class="left listuser_">
    <div id="divusers"></div>
</div>
<div class="right contentchat_">
    <div id="divChatWindow"></div>
    <div class="flex items-center fullpage">
        <asp:TextBox ID="_txtmessenger" AutoCompleteType="None" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    </div>
    <div id="btsendmessenger"><i class="las la-paper-plane"></i></div>
</div>

<input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdUserAvatar" type="hidden" />

<script>
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
        registerClientMethods(chatHub);
        // Start Hub
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            registerEvents(chatHub)

        });
    });
    function registerEvents(chatHub) {
        var name = '<%= this.UserID %>';
        if (name.length > 0) {
            chatHub.server.connect(name);
        }
    }   
    function registerClientMethods(chatHub) {

        // Calls when user successfully logged in
        chatHub.client.onConnected = function (id, userName, allUsers, messages, times) {

            $('#hdId').val(id);
            $('#hdUserName').val(userName);

            // Add All Users
            //for (i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {

            //    AddUser(chatHub, allUsers[i].ConnectionId, allUsers[i].UserName, allUsers[i].times);
            //}

            // Add Existing Messages
            for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                AddMessage(messages[i].UserName, messages[i].Message, messages[i].Time, messages[i].UserImage);

            }
        }

        // On New User Connected
        chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected = function (id, name, UserImage, loginDate) {
            AddUser(chatHub, id, name, UserImage, loginDate);
        }
        chatHub.client.messageReceived = function (userName, message, time, userimg) {

            AddMessage(userName, message, time, userimg);
        }

        chatHub.client.sendPrivateMessage = function (fromUserName) {

            createPrivateChat(chatHub, fromUserName);
        }

    }
    function AddUser(chatHub, id, name) {

        var userId = $('#hdId').val();

        var code = "";

        if (userId == id) {

            code = $('<div class="loginUser">' + name + "</div>");

        }
        else {

            code = $('<a id="' + id + '" class="user" >' + name + '<a>');

            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            if (userId != id)
                createPrivateChat(chatHub, id);
        }

        $("#divusers").append(code);

    }
    function createPrivateChat(chatHub, userId) {
        $('#btsendmessenger').click(function () {

            var msg = $("#_txtmessenger").val();

            if (msg.length > 0 && msg.trim().replace(/'/g, '')) {

                var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();
                var userAvatar = $('#hdUserAvatar').val();

                var date = new Date();
                var datetext = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
                chatHub.server.sendPrivateMessage(userId, userName, msg, datetext, userAvatar);
                $("#_txtmessenger").val('');
                document.getElementById('_txtmessenger').focus();
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('_txtmessenger').focus();
                document.getElementById("_txtmessenger").value = "";
            }

        });
        $("#_txtmessenger").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#btsendmessenger').click();
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('_txtmessenger').focus();
    }
    function AddMessage(userName, message, time, userimg) {
        var CurrUser = $('#hdUserName').val();
        var Side = '_cusms left';

        if (CurrUser == userName) {
            Side = '_myms right';
        }
        var divChat =
            '<div class="direct-chat-msg mb-20 ' + Side + '">' +
                '<div class="flex gap10 item_chat_">' +
                    '<div class="w50">' +
                        '<img src="' + userimg + '" class="radius30 overflow-hidden">' +
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="flex-col w50per">' +
                        '<div class="info_us flex">' +
                            '<div class="font-600 text-14">' + userName + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="font-300 text-12">' + time + '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="_messenger">' + message + '</div>' +
                    '</div>'+
                '</div >'+                    
            '</div>';

        $('#divChatWindow').append(divChat);
        var height = $('#divChatWindow')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('#divChatWindow').scrollTop(height);
    }
</script>
```

**The problem is how when I click the button on Page1 it gets the `ConnectionId` values and redirects to Page2**. Because in Page2 this is the place for live chat.

What do I have to do to make that happen? I wonder if it's possible to use cookies to save it. Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you!